# SCNText with background view having color and corner radius

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scntext

I have a requirement to add some text (for example, count) to the scene kit. The text has some background color and that background must be in circular shape as shown below:

[image]

The text must be in centre to the background view, even the count is in two digit numbers.For example count 55. I tried this using SCNText and SCNPlane, but didn't get good results. How can we achieve this in SceneKit?

Comment: Have you considered, or are you willing to consider, using SpriteKit as an overlay for this kind of graphical addition?

Comment: @Confused  Yes. Please post the answer if it is possible with spritekit.

Comment: It's possible with SpriteKit, but I'm a TERRIBLE coder. It would take me about a day (all its hours) to writeup an example of how to do this, with code. I'm about a line per hour. This is, as I've said somewhere else, less than my cocaine habit.